# JFileChooser dialog , messed up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

JFileChooser dialog , messed up after a secondary JFrame opens.
I post you the photos.

Here is the JFileChooser , opens after Open File button

[image]

seems perfect right??Now I press Options button

```
    private void openFileBtn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

Params ax=new Params();

ax.createGUI();

ax.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560,450));
ax.setVisible(true);
ax.pack();
ax.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.NORMAL);
    }
```

JFrame , I mean params class instance opens perfectly.This is supposed to return some values to the main window.However in order to debug this I have removed any references.
Now I open JFileChooser again and I take back this mess.
[image]

It's weird right??Sorry for not posting the code , its too big.I choose to let you ask the code you need.I hope this is more convenient to you.

Comment: Looks like the old-ish GTK-style file chooser. Do any of your other windows change appearance?

Comment: Indeed I have differend declaration of look and feel in the second window.That was what I was looking at , right now.

Comment: Show me how you change the look and feel. Because AFAIK, you can't change that per window, only for the entire program!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used different look and feel in the second window.
I change it and seems to work fine.
That was after immibis help.Thank you a lot immibis.

Now I use

```
try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

in both my main and the second window I open.
FIXED !!

Comment: You should set the look and feel once and not modify it again while the program is running

Comment: I am completely noob.When I make different windows(example frames) I use try{look and feel} in every window (or instance) I open.Is this a mistake?

Comment: *"When I make different windows(example frames)"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) *"I use try{look and feel} in every window (or instance) I open.Is this a mistake?"* Definitely.  Set the PLAF in the main before adding creating components. All components thereafter will use that PLAF - so will appear consistent.

Comment: Then don't call that classes main method